# Routing rails apps based on uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I am attempting to migrate two Ruby on Rails apps as they are currently hosted by the original developer who will not allow us access to change the code. The apps are a LocomotiveCMS_Engine and a Spree site. I have them rackup'd just fine running on port 3000 and 3333 respectively.

What I'd like to know is how to make it so that when you go to the page i.e. localhost it will route you to port 3000 and when you go to localhost/store it will route you to port 3333.

I attempted to use this: http://livsey.org/blog/2012/02/23/using-rack-proxy-to-serve-multiple-rails-apps-from-the-same-domain-and-port/ Which works for localhost requests, but when you go to localhost/store the assets of the page don't load correctly so there are no graphics on the page.

I am not extremely familiar with Ruby on Rails so I'm doing my best to piece it together. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the easiest way is to host them separately then redirect

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing or am I confused..? And redirect how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assets don't load correctly because Spree application is generating relative links to your assets, without `/store` prefix.

You can fix that by changing `asset_host` config in your Spree aplication. Set this in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.asset_host = "http://localhost/store"
```

Comment: Thank you this worked with a small modification of setting config.asset_host = "http://localhost:3333"